# How to convert utf8 string to unicode code point in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, codepoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF-8 to Unicode Code Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106470/utf-8-to-unicode-code-points)

UTF-8 strings are to be converted to Unicode code points. How to convert utf8 string to its corresponding unicode code point?

Comment: I dont think this question has been asked earlier!