# Unicode encode string

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm `json_encoding` some strings. Sometimes they contain binary data. This causes the encoding to fail with error code `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`. Running the strings through `utf8_encode` gets around this error. However, `✓` (a unicode checkmark) gets encoded as `\u00e2\u009c\u0093` which when interpreted by JavaScript and rendered in your browser actually looks like `â`.

How can I fix this? Is there another encoding I can use?

---

```
echo json_encode(utf8_encode('✓')); // "\u00e2\u009c\u0093"
```

Now press F12 and paste that into your JavaScript console (quotes included). It should output `â`.

---

Please note that

```
echo json_encode('✓'); // "\u2713"
```

Works as intended. The issue is that *sometimes* the string will contain binary data which `json_encode` can't handle, so I need to sanitize every string without breaking the strings it *can* handle.

---

More examples:

```
json_encode(chr(200));              // false (bad)
json_encode(utf8_encode(chr(200)))  // "\u00c8" (good)
json_encode('✓');                   // "\u2713" (good)
json_encode(utf8_encode(chr(200)))  // "\u00e2\u009c\u0093" (bad)
```

So you see, encoding it works well for some strings and breaks others.

This is strictly for *logging*. I don't care if the binary data comes out weird, I just don't want it to mess with valid strings.

Comment: Can you show your example PHP and JS code?

Comment: Maybe the problem relies in the document charset. Did you tried to add `<meta charset="UTF-8">`in the head of the HTML document?

Comment: @hek2mgl I pretty much gave it to you, but nevertheless, I updated the question.

Comment: @collimarco Yes, I did. I believe the correct encoding should be `"\u2713"` -- that renders fine.

Comment: This question is unanswerable. Encoding arbitrary binary data is one thing, keeping UTF-8 characters intact is something completely separate. What's to stop `0xe29c93` from being interpreted as ✓ when it shows up in your binary data?

Comment: `chr(200)` isn't a valid unicode char

Answer (score 1):

Running strings through this function

```
function _utf8($str) {
    if(!mb_check_encoding($str, 'UTF-8')) {
        return utf8_encode($str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

(taken and modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7106686/65387))

Seems to give the results I'm after.

Checkmarks are left alone, but `chr(200)` and other weirdness is encoded:

```
json_encode(utf8_encode(chr(200))) // "\u00c8"
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This question is unanswerable. Encoding arbitrary binary data is one thing, keeping UTF-8 characters intact is something completely separate. What's to stop the byte sequence `0xe29c93` from being interpreted as `✓` when it shows up in your binary data?

According to the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) PHP reference page, you can use the following syntax to encode Unicode characters:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

It should make it pass unicode characters through unescaped.

Comment: Tried it already. Doesn't work: `json_encode(chr(200),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` yields false.

Comment: re: "What's to stop..." I don't actually care if that shows up in my binary data. I just need it not break (return false) for data it can't handle.

Comment: @Mark Then transfer it into an encoding it will always be able to handle. For example, base64 encode it.

Comment: That would make valid strings illegible. It's for logging. I want to be able to read the valid strings. I'll visually ignore any binary data.