# Display chinese characters WITHOUT using utf8 encoding?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm fetching rows from a MySQL database with a `unicode_general_ci` collation. Columns contains chinese characters such as 格拉巴酒和蒸馏物 and I need to display those characters.

I **know that** I should work in utf-8 encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**but I can't**: I'm working on a legacy application where most of the `.php` files are saved as ANSI and the whole site is using:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Is there any way to display them?

**Bonus question**: I've tried to manually change the encoding in Chrome (Tool -> Encodig -> UTF-8) and It seems it doesn't work: page is reloaded but ???? are displayed instead of chinese characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can. iso-8859-1 is commonly called "Latin 1". There's no support for any Asian kanji-type languages at all.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

> ISO 8859-1 encodes what it refers to as "Latin alphabet no. 1," consisting of 191 characters from the Latin script. This character-encoding scheme is used throughout the Americas, Western Europe, Oceania, and much of Africa. It is also commonly used in most standard romanizations of East-Asian languages.

Comment: "Kanji" is the Japanese term. The Chinese term is "hanzi".

Comment: I was afraid of this. I suppose my only chance is to do some trick to only use utf8 in the specific page(s).

Comment: @tripleee Hence why I used "kanji-type". Nice to know the proper term tho

Answer (score 3):

You can display [格](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/683c/index.htm)
using the numeric entity reference `&#26684;`, etc. The encoding of the page should not matter in this case; HTML entity references always refer to Unicode code points.

PHP has a function [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for this purpose, but it appears that you will need workarounds for handling numeric entities. This [`json_encode` hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7107750/874188) is fairly obscure, but is probably programmatically the simplest.

```
echo preg_replace('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/', '&#x$1;', 
     preg_replace('^/"(.*)"$/', '$1', json_encode($s)));
```

This leverages the fact that `json_encode` will coincidentally do the conversion for you; the rest is all mechanics. (I guess that's PHP for you.)

> [IDEone demo](http://ideone.com/3TgQQq)

Your "bonus question" isn't really a question, but of course, that's how it works; raw bytes in the range 128-255 are only rarely valid UTF-8 sequences, so unless what you have on the page is valid UTF-8, you are likely to get the "invalid character" replacement glyph for those bytes.

For the record, the first two Chinese Han glyphs in your text in UTF-8 would display as `æ ¼æ‹‰` if mistakenly displayed in Windows [code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (what you, and oftentimes Microsoft, carelessly refer to as "ANSI") -- if you have those bytes on the page then forcing the browser to display it in UTF-8 should actually work as a workaround as well.

For additional background I recommend @deceze's [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs to Know About Encodings and Character Sets to Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Yep, but how to convert utf-8 string to html entities?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106470/utf-8-to-unicode-code-points has some ideas but they all seem to have flaws.