# How to convert a UTF-8 string to HEX codepoint in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I get the HEX codepoint from a UTF-8 string via `json_encode` as

```
substr(json_encode($str), 1, -1);
```

However, `json_encode` does not convert the characters at the ASCII range. For example,

For

```
sÆs
```

I get

```
s\u00C6s
```

but I want to get

```
\u0073\u00C6\u0073
```

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213288/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take json_encode for multibyte characters and assemble it for the ASCII characters.

```
function utf8toUnicode($str){
  $unicode = "";
  $len = mb_strlen($str);
  for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    $utf8char = mb_substr($str,$i,1);
    $unicode .= strlen($utf8char)>1
      ?trim(json_encode($utf8char),'"')
      :('\\u00'.bin2hex($utf8char))
    ;
  }
  return $unicode;
} 

$str = 'sÆs'; 

echo utf8toUnicode($str);  // \u0073\u00c6\u0073
```